# Help with decoding transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

I am using bitcoind and trying to import the blockchain data in database.

I have problem with this transaction: 
71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d

First three output addresses are missing. what is going on?

```
[root@nas blockchainwalker]# bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d 1
{
  "hex": "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",
  "txid": "71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d",
  "hash": "71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d",
  "size": 452,
  "vsize": 452,
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "11c88f6e655d69b8805f23a58b664a76af508c9d1ef128399ea82b5f45a9448a",
      "vout": 3,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "3045022100833d563254607e335be307b64caa97fba7c00a8a0d109c9ee4c10beaf8e913ac0220341428c10b5f55c8c273e212cdee63c7f19ce4106c38d133f4f41182b58afc7d[ALL] 0471a456d68af4fb16e800aef446adab5baed07a90e1e60726e974c55e4cb0ac619ac82f4161f93036b4eab2177e5ed300b9ce7b29e1ba9e0de7f880006c26d71c",
        "hex": "483045022100833d563254607e335be307b64caa97fba7c00a8a0d109c9ee4c10beaf8e913ac0220341428c10b5f55c8c273e212cdee63c7f19ce4106c38d133f4f41182b58afc7d01410471a456d68af4fb16e800aef446adab5baed07a90e1e60726e974c55e4cb0ac619ac82f4161f93036b4eab2177e5ed300b9ce7b29e1ba9e0de7f880006c26d71c"
      },
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00000001,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "9e000000416e6f7468657220746578742077617320656d62656464656420696e746f2074686520626c6f636b20636861696e2e20546865207374616e6461726420 OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "419e000000416e6f7468657220746578742077617320656d62656464656420696e746f2074686520626c6f636b20636861696e2e20546865207374616e6461726420ac",
        "type": "pubkey"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.00000001,
      "n": 1,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "227472616e73616374696f6e20746f204950206164647265737322207472616e73616374696f6e20747970652077617320757365642c2074686520646174612077 OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "41227472616e73616374696f6e20746f204950206164647265737322207472616e73616374696f6e20747970652077617320757365642c2074686520646174612077ac",
        "type": "pubkey"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.00000001,
      "n": 2,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "617320656d62656464656420696e746f20746865207075626c6963206b65792e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "41617320656d62656464656420696e746f20746865207075626c6963206b65792e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ac",
        "type": "pubkey"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "value": 0.01799994,
      "n": 3,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 73849283a878f884da3d161bbec6b33e04a6f3f1 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "hex": "76a91473849283a878f884da3d161bbec6b33e04a6f3f188ac",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "pubkeyhash",
        "addresses": [
          "1BXoXM7tqBgq4hF1ieXHCfm3QY3c6hCJuZ"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "blockhash": "000000000000049d2e0c8d934948568ecfb3f20231151f98390c594f500232f7",
  "confirmations": 302809,
  "time": 1338076296,
  "blocktime": 1338076296
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are `pay-to-pubkey` outputs. blockchain.info can not associate such outputs with an addresses but some other blockexplorers can

- https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d/
- https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/71bbaef28e09d8d6fadd41f053db7768dbb5fa4570f06b961dfc29db3dc00b1d

> can public key owner be able to spent the funds from the "missing"
>   address?

No. These outputs have valid format but invalid public key encoding. In fact, these are not the public keys, but some data embedded into the blockchain
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The output from `bitcoind` is correct.

This transaction has 3 pay-to-pubkey outputs, which do not have any associated address.

In order to identify which key they're sending to, some sites will in fact show them as if they were the corresponding pay-to-pubkey-hash output, and show the address for that. That is misleading, as there is no actual send to those addresses.

Comment: can public key owner be able to spent the funds from the "missing" address? Also see what I wrote in my own answer.

Comment: Of course they can. It's sent to a public key directly, so that public key can sign for spending. It's just not sent to an address.

Comment: they can not. see my answer

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be some problem with bitcoind.

Transaction can be decripted here:
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/decodetx/

**update**

I also found this explanation
https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin/issues/47